# referencing variable inside class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, class-variables

I an a newbie working with javascript / came from the PHP world / so pardom my ignorance.
I can't access `this._target` variable inside a `fetchPartial()` and I can't see what I am doing wrong.

My error is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._target')`

Can you help me pelase?

```
'use strict';

class View {
    constructor(partial, target) {
        this._partial = partial
        this._target = target;
    }
    
    fetchPartial() {
        fetch(this._partial).then(function (response) {
            // The API call was successful!
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (html) {
            let elem = document.querySelector( this._target ) // error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._target')
            elem.innerHTML = html
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // There was an error
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        });
    }
}

let p = new View('/_partial.html', '#_partial');
p.fetchPartial();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```js
fetchPartial() {
        fetch(this._partial).then(function (response) {
            // The API call was successful!
            return response.text();
        }).then(function (html) {
            let elem = document.querySelector( this._target ) // error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._target')
            elem.innerHTML = html
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // There was an error
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        });
    }
```

You should do:

```js
fetchPartial() {
        fetch(this._partial).then(function (response) {
            // The API call was successful!
            return response.text();
        }).then((html) => {
            let elem = document.querySelector( this._target ) // error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._target')
            elem.innerHTML = html
        }).catch(function (err) {
            // There was an error
            console.warn('Something went wrong.', err);
        });
    }
```

Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks this is working now